# Why is spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy and physical-strategy being ignored and FK columns have underscores?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Holiday {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private LocalDate date;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Calendar calendar;
    
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Calendar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    
}
```

When I run an integration test, I'm getting the following error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
> ResultSet     at
>
> ... 78 more Caused by:
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name
> 'calendar_id'.    at

The database has calendarId as the FK. I know that underscore is the default but my application.yml file has:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

This should change have hibernate indicate the column as calendarId. Why does this not work? I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly name the column:

```
@Column(name = "Calendarid")
```